# Não estou conseguindo inserir dados no banco

Tags: php, html, mysql

Não estou conseguindo inserir dados no banco, eu estava usando o `PDO`, mas agora passei a usar o `MySql`, porque só consegui listar dados do banco com o `MySql`, estou conseguindo listar os dados porém não estou conseguindo inserir.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$bd = "nise";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd);
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
    echo"Falha na conexão: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.")".$mysqli->connect_error;

?>
```

Aqui está o arquivo `PHP`

```
<?php 
include("includes/conexao.php");//conexão com o banco

$consulta = "SELECT id, data, descricao, imagem, id_bloco, qual_descricao, id_denuncia_oque FROM denuncia";
$con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die ($mysqli->error);

if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){
    $query = "INSERT INTO resposta_denuncia (descricao_resposta, imagem, id_usuario) 
        VALUES (:descricao_resposta, :imagem, :id_usuario)";

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    $path = "img_denuncia/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path))

    $valores = array();
    $valores[':descricao_resposta'] = $_POST['descricao_resposta'];
    $valores[':imagem'] = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    $valores[':id_usuario'] = 2;

    if(!isset($_POST['descricao_resposta']) or empty($_POST['descricao_resposta'])) {
        echo 0;
    }elseif($result = $statement->execute($valores)) {
        echo 1; // dados enviados com sucesso
    } else {
        echo 0; // erro ao tentar enviar dados 
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: A identação do código não está adequada e leva a erros de interpretação igual nesse trecho: `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path))
    $valores = array();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tem dois problema, o primeiro é a falta de associar os valores com os placeholders a função `bind_param()` faz isso. O segundo a lib MySQLi não suporta named placeholders (`:nome`)  apenas parâmetros posicionais as interrogações.

O código deve ficar assim:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO resposta_denuncia (descricao_resposta, imagem, id_usuario) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('ssi', $valores[':descricao_resposta'], $valores[':imagem'], $valores[':id_usuario']);
```

Fiz uma refatoração para simplificar a lógica do código:

```
if(empty($_POST['descricao_resposta'])){
    exit('0 - descrição vazia');
}

if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){

    $path = "img_denuncia/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)){

        $valores[':descricao_resposta'] = $_POST['descricao_resposta'];
        $valores[':imagem'] = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
        $valores[':id_usuario'] = 2;        

        $query = "INSERT INTO resposta_denuncia (descricao_resposta, imagem, id_usuario) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('ssi', $valores[':descricao_resposta'], $valores[':imagem'], $valores[':id_usuario']);

        $msg = $statement->execute() ? '1 - sucesso' : 'erro no banco: '. $statement->error;

        exit($msg);
    }
}else{
    exit('0 - arquivo vazio');
}
```

Se estiver utilizando o php5.6 ou superior pode otimizar o `bind_param()` dessa forma:

```
$valores = [$_POST['descricao_resposta'], $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'], 2];     

$query = "INSERT INTO resposta_denuncia (descricao_resposta, imagem, id_usuario) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('ssi', ...$valores);
```

Lembre que os valores do array devem estar nas mesmas posições das colunas descritas pois a associação é pela posição.

Comment: Você poderia editar meu código com essas alterações que você disponibilizou, não to conseguindo ver onde eu coloco esse trecho de código.

Comment: @PauloVictor editei o código.